# How i can mask input semantic react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masking

I'm trying to mask a input semantic react date to just insert dates in format DD/MM/YYYY, i try to do this way:

```
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask'

...

 <DateInput
    name="date"
    mask="99/99/9999"
    placeholder="Data"
    value={this.props.data}
    dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
    onChange={this.props.changeDataTarefa}
    animation="none"
    >
       <MaskedInput guide={false} {...this.props} mask={[/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]} />
 </DateInput>
```

Also tried:

```
<MaskedInput
value={this.props.data}
onChange={this.props.changeDataTarefa}
mask={[/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
render={(ref, props) => (
    <DateInput
    name="date"
    placeholder="Data"
    {...props}
    innerRef={ref}
    dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
    animation="none"
    />
)}
/>
```

I'm actually trying to use [this mask component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-mask)
But this way i can

Comment: what is `DateInput`? is it a custom component? library component?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-calendar-react

Comment: what you're trying to do wont work, the package doesn't use the children and doesn't support masking. you may need to do the mask yourself manually

Comment: oops sorry was going to link to this in the last comment. https://github.com/arfedulov/semantic-ui-calendar-react/blob/master/src/views/InputView.tsx